# Tkinter не появляются кнопки

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg="#dddf99")
canvas.pack()

frame =tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx =0.1, rely=0.1)

openFile = tk.Button(root, text="Open File", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#263D42")
openFile.pack()

runApps = tk.Button(root, text="Run Apps", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#263D42")
runApps.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Не появляются две кнопки: Open File и Run Apps

Comment: Не знаю у меня все появилось...

Comment: Если экран не очень большой (например разрешение 768 пикселей в высоту, при том что  размер canvas - 700x700), то кнопки уедут за границу экрана или панель задач.

Answer (score 1):

Вы добавляете кнопки ниже холста, и если у вас экран с разрешением 768 пикселей в высоту, при том что размер холста 700x700, и панель задач не скрывается, то кнопки уедут под панель задач.

Вот пример:

[image: Скриншот]

Уменьшаем высоту холста до 650:

[image: А вот и кнопочки]

Для сравнения - на экране с большим разрешением, без изменений программы:

[image: На большом разрешении]